# Out Of Memory in IBM Websphere 8.5.5.7

Tags: websphere

I am throwing a question on Out of Memory in IBM Websphere 8.5.5.7....We have an application primarily a Spring RestFull Webservices application deployed in IBM WAS 8.5.5.7. getting the below Out of Memory error for the last 5 days

```
[2/3/16 13:12:51:651 EST] 000000ab BBFactoryImpl E   CWOBB9999E: Something unexpected happened; the data (if any) is <null> and the exception (if any) is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at 
com.ibm.oti.vm.VM.getClassNameImpl(Native Method) at 
com.ibm.oti.vm.AbstractClassLoader.getPackageName(AbstractClassLoader.java:384) at 
com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:65) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:691) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:680) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:693) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:680) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:502) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.buddy.RegisteredPolicy.loadClass(RegisteredPolicy.java:79) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.buddy.PolicyHandler.doBuddyClassLoading(PolicyHandler.java:135) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:494) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410) at 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:693) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:680) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(DelegatingClassLoader.java:51) at 
sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:57) at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:437) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:363) at 
sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:433) at 
sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:149) at 
sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:316) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1409) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:63) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:515) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:363) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:491) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:338) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:625) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1619) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1619) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1768) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364) at 
com.ibm.son.util.Util.deserialize(Util.java:434) at 
com.ibm.son.mesh.AbstractTCPImpl.procReceivedMessage(AbstractTCPImpl.java:478) at 
com.ibm.son.mesh.CfwTCPImpl.completedRead(CfwTCPImpl.java:1248) at 
com.ibm.son.mesh.CfwTCPImpl.complete(CfwTCPImpl.java:1061) at 
com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818) at 
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) at 
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) at 
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) at 
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) at 
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) at 
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProces
```

Analyzed on the Introscope and Heap Analyser for the heap dump  It is observed that consistently the lion share of the memory (>60%) is being consumed by `com/ibm/xml/xlxp2/scan/util/SimpleDataBufferFactory` used by IBM stax parser with WAS
 Introscope Analysis throws light on  sudden spike in the thread count, memory usage and gradual increase in connection count when the OOM happened.

When checking on the `com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.util.Databuffer` issue of taking more heapsize , its being seen that IBM has been fixing Out Of Memory Issues for classes belong to com.ibm.xml.xlxp.scan.util/com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.util in WAS 6, WAS 7 and WAS 8 servers.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM39346
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM08333

Can anyone share any idea whether this an issue with IBM WAS 8.5.5.7...could not get a solid break

Comment: Would this be related? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM96380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the out of memory problems concerning `com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.util.DataBuffer` were addressed with system properties that users can configure to reduce the memory used by the IBM StAX parser.

The following system properties can be helpful in resolving out of memory issues with the IBM StAX parser. Each of them should be available in WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5.7.

```
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.encoding.DataSourceFactory.bufferLength
```

System property which controls the size of the StAX parser's data buffers. The default value is 65536.

Setting this property to a smaller value such as 2048 may reduce the memory usage if the 64KB buffers were only being partially filled by the InputStream when they are in use. The buffers are cached within the StAX parser (inside `com/ibm/xml/xlxp2/scan/util/SimpleDataBufferFactory`) so a reduction in memory usage there would reduce the overall memory linked to each StAX parser object.

```
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.Pool.STRONG_REFERENCE_POOL_MAXIMUM_SIZE
```

System property (introduced by APAR [PM42465](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM42465)) which limits the number of XMLStreamReaders (and XMLStreamWriters) that will be cached using strong references. Follow the instructions at the link provided on how to set this property.

```
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.encoding.DataSourceFactory.bufferLoadFactor
```

The value of this system property is a non-negative integer which determines the minimum number of bytes (as a percentage) that will be loaded into each buffer. The percentage is calculated with the following formula 1 / (2^n).

When the system property is not set its default value is 3. Setting the property to a lower value than the default can improve memory usage but may also reduce throughput.

```
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.util.SymbolMap.maxSymbolCount
```

System property (introduced by APAR [PI08415](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI08415)). The value of this property is a non-negative integer which determines the maximum size of the StAX parser's symbol map. Follow the instructions at the link provided on how to set this property.